# Can a supermarket be viewed as a marketmaker (like market makers that operate on the financial markets)?

Tags: markets, retail-economics

Marketmakers are traders who set the price on a financial market, because they have an obligation to buy.

Can a supermarket be viewed as a marketmaker (like market makers that operate on the financial markets)?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for your definition of marketmaker?

Comment: Also, the supermarket does not have any obligation to buy, so I don't think it fits your own definition on this count.

Comment: I think it is often the case that they have a contract with a supplier where they have to buy a certain amount for a certain period, so in that case they have.

Comment: "A certain amount", and from that supplier, not from anyone, so that seems different. Have you tried selling stuff to a supermarket? Not much of a market in this sense.